# Scala DataTable to List of Maps

Tags: scala, datatable, cucumber

Could you please suggest how I can implement the following :

I have a dataTable in a Cucumber feature file such as :

```
|A  |B  |C  |
|1  |2  |3  |
|11 |22 |33 |
|111|222|333|
```

I try to get a List of Maps like this:

```
A:1,11,111; B:2,22,222; C:3,33,333
```

If I do like this

```
List[Map[String, Any]] = 
  data.asMaps(classOf[String], classOf[Any]).asScala.map(_.asScala.toMap).toList
```

I got a bit another staff: A:1, B:2, C:3, A:11 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose, and then map to Maps.

```
val source = List(
  List("A", "B", "C"),
  List(1, 2, 3),
  List(11, 22, 33),
  List(111, 222, 333)
)

val transposed = source.transpose

println(transposed) // List(List(A, 1, 11, 111), List(B, 2, 22, 222), List(C, 3, 33, 333))

val mapped = transposed.map {
  case l: List[Any] => Map(l.head -> l.tail)
}

println(mapped) // List(Map(A -> List(1, 11, 111)), Map(B -> List(2, 22, 222)), Map(C -> List(3, 33, 333)))
```

Comment: Thanks. but there was an error in 'mapped', by default size of Array 15, so, if I had only 3 values - I still got 15 entries. So modified this a bit `l => Map(l.head -> l.tail)`